# Accessing parent document from IFrame (same domain) giving error

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, redirect

I am trying to access the parent's document from an iframe using `window.parent.document`, but i am getting this error -

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://abc.xyz.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

But the host of both parent and the iframe are the same.
Both have the host `https://abc.xyz.com`

In the iframe, I am redirecting it through a few URLs. So it starts from

`https://abc.xyz.com` 
then goes to

`https://www.facebook.com`

then is redirected again to 
`https://abc.xyz.com`

I am trying to access the document after this redirection, but am getting this error.
Any thoughts on why this could happen? Please help.

Comment: `https://abc.xyz.com -> https://www.facebook.com` = Cross Origin... I may be missing the point though?!

Comment: I am accessing the parent's document from the iframe after it has been redirected from www.facebook.com to https://abc.xyz.com again

Comment: What is the value of `src` on your iframe when accessing the parent document? A cleaner solution would be to use postMessage.

Comment: the src of my iframe when im trying to access the parent document is - 
`https://abc.xyz.com/addCards`

Comment: Hmm, that does seem odd. Maybe there's some caching taking place that's getting it into a pickle? Sorry I can't be of any more help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `postMessage` (Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)).

In your iframe call this:

```
window.parent.postMessage({message: 'stuff you want to send'}, 'https://abc.xyz.com/');
```

In the parent window you can listen for the message event like this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(evt) {
   if(evt.origin == 'https://abc.xyz.com/')
       console.log('Data: ' + evt.data.message);
}, false);
```

Comment: Yes i am able to use postMessage. I am just wondering why am i not able to access parent's document, even though im back on the same domain as the parent now after  a slew of redirections

Comment: Because browsers try to better be overprotective than underprotective. (Dont know the exact technical reason).